# Excel VBA: date format in user form

Tags: excel, textbox, userform, vba

I have various text boxes in a user form with dates pulled from my worksheets, but all the dates are in US format (`m/d/yyyy`).

I'm using the `ControlSource` property to copy the date, e.g.:

```
ControlSource='SKU Data'!N2
```

Is there a way to reformat the dates so they appear as `d/m/yyyy`?

The dates in the worksheets are already formatted to `d/m/yyyy.`

Comment: `Format(`(whatever your value is)`, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks, I tried the format but, this has not worked. Oddly one of my user form textbox dates is OK. Could it be the format on the worksheet that is effecting the textbox format?

Comment: Just to be clear, the above code line will return the date in the format you want but not actually paste it anywhere on the spreadsheet. You need to tell the code where it goes. For example: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = Format(1/13/1987, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

Do it with **String**s:

```
Sub dural()
    txt = "12/25/2014"
    a = Split(txt, "/")
    txt = a(1) & "/" & a(0) & "/" & a(2)
    MsgBox txt
End Sub
```